# The method foo(int[][]) in the type foo is not applicable for the arguments (int)

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente método. Al llamar al método `construyeVector()` me da el error:

> The method construyeVector(int[][]) in the type ArrayDouble is not
>   applicable for the arguments (int).

No sé qué está pasando. Alguna indicación por favor.

```
private static int[][]  matriz;
private static int filas;
private static int columnas;
private static int [] vector;

public void ordenaBurbuja(int [] vector, int [][] matriz) {

    int aux;

    construyeVector(matriz[filas][columnas]);

    for ( int k=0; k<vector.length-1;k++) {
        for(int k2=0; k2<vector.length-k-1;k2++) {
            if(vector[k2]>vector[k2+1]) {
                aux=vector[k2+1];
                vector[k2+1]=vector[k2];
                vector[k2]=aux;
            }
        }
    }
    for(int l= 0; l<vector.length;l++) {
        System.out.print(vector[l]+" ");
    }
}
```

El método al que llama es:

```
public int construyeVector(int matriz2[][]) {
    vector =new int[columnas*filas];
    int j=0;
    for(int i=0;i<filas;i++) {
        for(int i2=0;i2<columnas;i2++) {
            vector[j]=matriz2[i][i2];
            j++;
        }
    }

    return vector[j];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Veo muchas cosas sin sentido en tu código.

Cuando llamas a la función de la que hablas `construyeVector()`, le estás pasando un elemento de la matriz, y no toda la matriz, como parece ser que es lo que querrías que pasara.

`matriz[filas][columnas]` ->>>> Es un elemento de la matriz, concretamente el que está en la fila indicada por el valor de `filas` y la columna indicada por el valor de `columnas`.

Si lo que quieres es pasar la matriz entera, tienes que pasar la variable sin corchetes ni nada:

```
construyeVector(matriz);
```

Pero esto tampoco tiene sentido porque dentro de la función `construyeVector` haces referencia a variables globales `filas` y `columnas` que espero tengas inicializadas antes de llegar ahí. Sino, te creará un vector de 0 elementos y no entrará en ninguno de los dos `for`, puesto que `filas` y `columnas` tendrán valor 0.

Además, la función `contruyeVector` retorna un vector pero no estás asignando ese retorno a ninguna variable en la función `ordenaBurbuja`. Así que todo lo que hagas en `construyeVector` se perdería al salir de la misma.

En definitiva, vas a tener que darle otra vuelta a tu código.

Comment: Muchas gracias por las indicaciones. Llevo poco tiempo programando. Las variables sí están inicializadas con otros métodos. construyeVector() solo se ejecuta cuando ejecuto ordenaBurbuja(). construyeVector() almacena los datos en la variable vector[]. Por tu comentario creo que deberia ser o un método void o eliminar la variable global ¿no?. La verdad que no sé si son las formas correctas de hacerlo.

Comment: Puedes hacer una de las dos cosas con el vector, pero no las dos. O usas la variable global y que las funciones la usen, o la vas pasando  a las funciones que la usen y/o la retornan. Pero dejar las dos, global y local y con el mismo nombre no va a causarte más que problemas.

Comment: En realidad en Java no hay variables globales. Son variables miembro de la clase o variables definidas en funciones . Así que cómo definas la variable dependerá de lo que necesites. Si es una variable que tiene que persistir durante la vida del objeto de esa clase, pues la defines miembro. Si es una variable temporal, la defines en una función.